# Cannot get checkbox full value

Tags: jquery, html

```
 <div id="panel">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td><input  type="checkbox" value="Sales Engineering" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input  type="checkbox" value="Marketing fiedls" /></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to get the checkbox values like below

```
var listofParameters = $('#panel :input');
for (var index in listofParameters) {
    var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).val();
}
```

But I am only getting the value up to the first space, not the full value. For my code, I got the following output:

```
Sales 
Marketing
```

I expect the output to be like

```
Sales Engineering
Marketing fields .
```

What is the problem in my code ?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your HTML is actually different and you forgot quotes around the attribute value:

```
<input type="checkbox" value=Sales Engineering />
```

That won't work. Now `Engineering` is regarded as attribute and `Sales` is the value of the `value` attribute (as you can already see through the syntax highlighting). [Here is a demo without quotes](http://jsfiddle.net/rgQ29/2/).

But the HTML you posted in your question, i.e. with quotes, [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rgQ29/1/). So make sure you really have quotation marks around the attribute value.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).val();
```

to

```
var listofParameters = $('#panel :input'), ste;
for (var index in listofParameters) {
    ste += $(listofParameters[index]).val();
```

Comment: that shouldn't work since you are re-declaring ste each time; if you want to do it that way, you need to declare ste before the loop

Comment: @DarthVader in javascript there is no block level scope, it has always function level scope

Comment: @DarthVader: JavaScript has function scope, not block scope. All variables are implicitly delared at the top of function, no matter where `var` is.

Comment: @DarthVader javascript does something called has hoisting to do this

Comment: sorry, my comment was directed at the original for loop, i put it in the wrong place; Sudhir's code is fine

Comment: @DarthVader: Even in the OPs code it is not a problem, for the same reasons.